# Attaching datamapper operator to ruby symbol and put into hash

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I have:

```
{xyz => [:abc, :klm, :nop]}
```

I want to have something like this dynamically (22, 33, 44 are some random values):

```
{:abc.gte => 22, :klm.gte => 33, :nop.gte => 44}
```

`gte` is a Datamapper operator, as documented at http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html

Does anyone have an idea how to build the second hash?

Comment: What do you want to do with that hash later?

Comment: I want to pass that hash to Datamapper to retrieve all data from model  product. E.g. Product.all(newhash)  this will give me all rows where abc >= 22 and klm >= 33 and nop >= 44

Comment: Ah, I see. It's simpler than I thought :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the min/max of random values?

Let's suppose it is a range from 1 to 100. Then you simply do like this:

```
require 'data_mapper'

properties = [:abc, :klm, :nop]
rand_range = (1..100).to_a

hash = properties.inject({}) { |h, p| h.update p.gte => rand_range.sample  }
p hash
```

and you get a hash that you can feed to datamapper's filter:

```
{#<DataMapper::Query::Operator @target=:abc @operator=:gte>=>24, #<DataMapper::Query::Operator @target=:klm @operator=:gte>=>52, #<DataMapper::Query::Operator @target=:nop @operator=:gte>=>51}
```

### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=attaching-datamapper-operator-to-ruby-symbol-and-put-into-hash.rb&run=true).